# Undelete error: entity is deleted

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql, undelete

I'm trying to undelete records using apex and it is throwing me an error: entity is deleted

```
List<MyObject__c> undeleteObj = [select id, Unique_Id__c from MyObject__c 
            where Unique_Id__c IN :uniqueIds];
undelete undeleteObj;
```

This code is in the trigger on after update. Schema is same, record does exists in org and I verified it in Real Force. I can't do this using data loader since it is part of workflow process where the record is undeleted if it was previously deleted else or a new record is added. Any suggestions/workarounds will be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried the above code with the `ALL ROWS` keyword in the query to bring back the deleted records?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not entirely sure but I think you would need to add `ALL ROWS` in your select statement otherwise it won't retrieve the deleted records

Comment: Also, `WHERE Unique_Id__c IN :uniqueIds AND IsDeleted = TRUE`, or you'd get an "Entity is not in the recycle bin" error.